# The TargetControlID of 'modalPopupExtender' is not valid. A control with ID 'tdDay' could not be found

Tags: asp.net

I am getting error when i use fallowing code. i have provide the target control id still error is occur.

Please help

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="repDays" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repDays_OnItemDataBound">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <td id="tdDay" runat="server">
                                <asp:Literal ID="litDay" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#43AAE4" BorderStyle="Solid"
                                BorderWidth="2px">
                                <div style="text-align: right; width: 100%">
                                    Some text in popup
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
                            <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopupExtender" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1"
                                TargetControlID="tdDay" DropShadow="true">
                            </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: thanks! I want to use hover for particular cell then what should i do?

Comment: Imho because of the `Repeater` which generates unique ID's for every item but the `TargetControlId` is an attribute that will be evaluated on client-side. Have a look at this similar question: http://forums.asp.net/t/1576354.aspx

Comment: i try to fallow your link but there are no any help. can you please help how to i use mouse hove on particular cell?